# What hash function is used for partitionkey mapping to partitionid in EventHub

Tags: azure, hash, partitioning, azure-eventhub

I am using an **Azure EventHub** to process customer events.

The **customer's id is used as partitionkey** for EventHub. The key will be hashed and is used to select an **EventHub partition**. All events for a given customer will end up on the same partition.

The [EventHub documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features) mentions the following:

> You can use a partition key to map incoming event data into specific partitions for the purpose of data organization. The partition key is a sender-supplied value passed into an event hub. It is processed through a static hashing function, which creates the partition assignment. If you don't specify a partition key when publishing an event, a round-robin assignment is used.

There are 10 partitions in my eventhub and now I'm trying to map which customers are ending up on the same partition-ids. A list of all customer ids is available.

However, I **cannot find documentation on the exact hashing function** used by EventHub to determine the matching partitionid.

If this is not available, what would be the best approach do determine the partitionid for a given partitionkey.

Comment: I've found this code, which is old, but still works: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/lts_2018-10-9/service/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/Common/EventHubPartitionKeyResolver.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is not publicly documented nor is there a supported way to determine the assigned partition for a given key. It is strongly advised that your application not assume that it can reproduce the service hash reliably.

If you need to understand what partition data appears in, it is recommended that your application assign a specific partition when publishing events.

That all said, the algorithm used is not an off-the-shelf standard, but a customized variation.  You'd need the source to be able to reproduce its results in all cases.

Comment: Thanks! So the only way I can inspect what data (partitionkey) is being mapped to what partition id, is by adding a consumergroup on the partitions and going through the data in the eventhub? Odd, this seemed like a common use case, eg: we currently have 100 customers and notice that one partition of the eventhub is slower compared to others - probably because some heavy customers are allocated to that partition. One wants to know what the distribution would be over the partitions without needing to process all data of the eventhub, no?

Comment: For that type of scenario, your application would be better off assigning partition identifiers rather than partition keys.  That enables you to choose the exact partition where data resides.  The service makes no guarantee about even distribution for keys, and they're not the right tool if you're trying to evenly balance customers among partitions.  Keys are useful when you don't care about what partition is used, only that the data is grouped together.